Spring Cloud Vault VaultTemplate URI not absolute error
I have an AWS Lambda in Java that needs to use Hashicorp's Vault encryption for encrypt data and send it off in transit. The Vault is set up in AWS as well so it's local to the Lambda. I have followed the doc's way of authentication through a STSClient and AWSIamAuthenticationOptions since the key is created/kept within the Vault within AWS and we have no power over it. However, whenever I follow that process and set up my VaultTemplate any operation on it results in a URI Not Absolute error, even though it clearly is.
Here's the snippet:
        StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
                .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
                .build();
        AssumeRoleRequest assumeRoleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                .roleArn(System.getenv("VAULT_ASSUMED_ROLE_ARN"))
                .build();
        stsClient.assumeRole(assumeRoleRequest);

        AwsIamAuthenticationOptions options = AwsIamAuthenticationOptions.builder()
                .role(System.getenv("VAULT_AUTH_ROLE"))
                .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
                .build();
        ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication = new AwsIamAuthentication(options, restOperations());
        VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint = VaultEndpoint.create(System.getenv("VAULT_IAM_SERVER_ID"), 8200);
        VaultTemplate vaultTemplate = new VaultTemplate(vaultEndpoint, clientAuthentication);
        VaultResponse vaultResponse = vaultTemplate.read("/secret/data/secret");
        return vaultResponse
}

